# How to populate a DropdownlistFor control from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

This is my controller code

```
 public static List<SelectListItem> GetDropDown()
{
        JurisprudenceDBEntities _db = new JurisprudenceDBEntities();
        var Lawyers = new List<tbl_Lawyer>();
        using (_db)
        {
            Lawyers = _db.tbl_Lawyer.ToList();
        }

    List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var temp in Lawyers)
    {
        ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.Name, Value = temp.LawyerID.ToString() });
    }
    return ls;
}
```

This is the control in the view

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Lawyer)
```

The name of the controller is case controller.

Comment: So what is your error/problem? Just an explanation of your method won't help us.

Comment: how do i populate the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm used to use a code like this to populate DropdownListFor  by Razor. I just include the DataBase inside the poject first (DAL):

```
public static SelectList GetDropDown()
    {
        using (var db = new DAL.JurisprudenceDBEntities())
        {
            var query = db.Lawyers.Select(o => new { o.LawyerID, o.Name, ... } );
            return new SelectList(query.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList(), "LawyerID", "Name");
        }
    }
```

In The control view you just put a Razor element like that:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Lawyer, GetDropDown(), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: i placed this in the model but i could not access the method from the view

Comment: Try to put the method ina separated class. I generally put the method in another class and, inside the DropDownListFor, i use `/*class name*/.GetDropDown()` instead of `GetDropDown()` only, try this and let me know if it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Lawyer, Model.GetDropDown(), null, null)
```

This is assuming that the "GetDropDown" method is in your model. If not, reference the appropriate class instead.

The MSDN documentation shows all the possible options you can pass to the DropDownListFor helper: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: how to reference the class ?

Comment: I see it's already a static method, which is good. So then just `MyClass.GetDropDown()`